# How to get value of json web API using VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, vue.js

I am new to Vue.JS. Actually I am trying to get Name of bank by typing routing number.

API: https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/name.json?rn=011103093

```
export default {
        data: function () {

            return {
                picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 7),
                resultsArray: {
                    'name' : '',
                    'message' : '',
                    'code' : '',
                    'rn' : ''
                },
         }
     }
   }

methods: {
           /* searchBasedOnMonthAndType() {
                let app = this;
                app.modeldailog = false
                app.rows = [];
                app.renderInvoicesBasedOnMonth(app.picker);
            },*/

            getBankName() {
                let app = this;
                app.rows = [];
                var rn = '011103093';
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/name.json?rn=' + rn,
                    success(res) {
                        if (res.results != null) {
                            app.resultsArray = res.results;
                        } else {
                            // console.log(app.resultsArray);
                            // console.log("test after");
                            alert("data not fetched");
                        }


                    }

                });
            },
}

<label>Routing Number</label>
 <input type="text" name="routingNo" v-validate="'required|numeric'"  v-model="paymentinfo.routing_no" class="form-control input-sm" v-on:keyup="getBankName();">

<label>Bank Name</label>
<input type="text" name="chck_bank_name" v-validate="'required'" class="form-control input-sm" v-bind:value="resultsArray.name">
```

I am getting Ajax response null. Everytime else part is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you typo in options for $.ajax method. Try this:

```
getBankName() {
  let app = this;
  app.rows = [];
  var rn = '011103093';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/name.json?rn=' + rn,
    success: (res) => {
      if (res != null) {
        app.resultsArray = res;
      } else {
         // console.log(app.resultsArray);
         // console.log("test after");
        alert("data not fetched");
      }
    }
  });
},
```

FYI: result of that api call is not array. it's like so:

```
{"name": "TD BANK NA", "message": "OK", "code": 200, "rn": "011103093"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use something like this:

```
$.ajax(...).done(data => {
  console.log(data)
}).fail(() => {
  console.log('fail')
})
```

P.S. It's better to use `const vm = this;` instead of `let app = this;`. It's de-facto standart in Vue.js